# How to generate Shared Dynamic Column Arrays in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a column array that needs to be shared with multiple table components and the data used to generate the array comes from global state (useContext). How do I create a function that returns an array that is built from hooks and other functions? It seems like it would need to be a React component to handle the hooks and functions, but those return components, not arrays.

This is what needs to get wrapped by something so it can be shared (not duplicated) across different table components.

```
import CategoryDropdown from '../common/CategoryDropdown';   

const {
       data: [data, setData],
       categories: [categories, setCategories]
    } = useContext(Activities);

  const handleCategoryChange = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {};
 
if (!(data && categories)) return [];

return [
  {
    field: 'name',
    fieldName: 'Name',
    headerName: `Name`,
    type: 'string',
    template: (dataItem) => {
      const { name } = dataItem;
      return name;
    }
  },
  {
    field: 'categoryId',
    fieldName: 'Category',
    headerName: 'Category',
    type: 'string',
    template: (dataItem) => {
      const { categoryId } = dataItem;
      return (
        <CategoryDropdown
          categoryId={categoryId}
          onChange={handleCategoryChange}
        />
      );
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write a custom hook in this case. custom hooks can be written like a simple function with using all react hooks in there, but you should call them in the react components. exactly like useState, useEffect, and etc.

`// useTableColumns hook`

```
import CategoryDropdown from '../common/CategoryDropdown';   

export const useTableColumns = () => {
    const {
      data: [data, setData],
      categories: [categories, setCategories]
    } = useContext(Activities);
    
    const handleCategoryChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {};
     
    if (!(data && categories)) return [];
    
    return [
      {
        field: 'name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        headerName: `Name`,
        type: 'string',
        template: (dataItem) => {
          const { name } = dataItem;
          return name;
        }
      },
      {
        field: 'categoryId',
        fieldName: 'Category',
        headerName: 'Category',
        type: 'string',
        template: (dataItem) => {
          const { categoryId } = dataItem;
          return (
            <CategoryDropdown
              categoryId={categoryId}
              onChange={handleCategoryChange}
            />
          );
        }
      }
    ];
}
```

Now you can use it in your components like bellow:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const columns = useTableColumns();
    
    // you can use the returned columns in this component
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!